# C# Hash string into short number

Tags: c#, string, hash

it's bugging me that I cannot find a solution for this seemingly trivial task.

I want to hash an arbitrary long string (e.g. 5000 characters) into a small number, e.g. 6 digits.

This hash should be deterministic and it should not matter which architecture or system it is running on (this is the tricky part).

Comment: How _good_ of a hash code do you need? Do you need to minimize collisions? You could do something as basic as adding up all of the character codes and taking the sum modulo 1E7.

Comment: What qualities in the hash code are going to be a satisfactory answer? Technically I could answer this question with `return 0;` - it's deterministic, it works on arbitrary strings, etc. The goodness of the hash code probably depends on your scenario; i.e., what strings you have, how much they vary, etc.

Comment: There's nothing "tricky" about writing a hash algorithm that works the same on multiple architectures. Look up Wang hash, Jenkins hash, MurmurHash, for example. Any one of those will do what you're asking, and you can take however many bits of the result you want. It'll certainly be faster than calling something like SHA256 or MD5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a standard hash function, e.g. SHA256:

```
    string str = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    byte[] encoded = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str));
    var value = BitConverter.ToUInt32(encoded, 0) % 1000000;
```

This is deterministic, platform-independent (as SHA256 is standardized), can use input of arbitrary length, and provides a "very" unique number for any string (i.e. it is very unlikely that you find another string with the same number, but that depends on the number of output bits that you are using).

Comment: This is better.

Comment: be aware for what you use it for, as there are reasons why the ToHashCode function in .net core has been changed to change every time the application was started (in contrast to .net framework that did not change between startups by default)(https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/26779#issuecomment-404328685)

Comment: @CitrusO2 that's an interesting point! Unfortunately the discussion on github only mentions the potential security issue without going into details. After a bit of research I found this quite well-written blog post: [Why is string.GetHashCode...](https://andrewlock.net/why-is-string-gethashcode-different-each-time-i-run-my-program-in-net-core/), which explains the possible denial-of-service attack, which may or may not be relevant for the context of this question.